# Clarification about Wald's notation on his General Relativity Book

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

In equation 4.1.4 Wald describes the metric in pre-relativistic physics as,

$$h_{ab} = \sum_{\mu, \nu} h_{\mu\nu}(\mathrm{d}x^{\mu})_a (\mathrm{d}x^{\nu})_b\tag{4.1.4}$$

with $h_{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(1,1,1)$.

My confusion is to what exactly is meant by $(\mathrm{d}x^{\mu})_a$ here?

Comment: Would you understand if Wald wrote $h_{ab}= \sum_{\mu, \nu} h_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu$? Do you understand what $dx^\mu$ is? If yes, then your question is most likely on the "abstract index notation", which is explained in the book. Also you should specify which book of Wald you are talking about...

Comment: I believe I understand the abstract index notation on it's own. These mixed coordinates and and abstract index expressions are what I find confusing. As to your question, the expression you wrote on the right is how I typically write metric tensors, so yes, that would make sense to me.

Comment: Anyways, I think your comment clarified how I should interpret the above expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Greek indices are used to label elements of an ordered set. For example an arbitrary element from a set of basis vectors $\{e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ would be labeled $e_\mu$ so that $\mu \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ denotes its order in the basis. Similarly an arbitrary expansion coefficient of a vector $v$ in this basis belongs to the set $\{v^0,v^1,v^2,v^3\}$ and would be labeled $v^\mu$ to label which basis vector it is associated with, so that $v = \sum_\mu v^\mu e_\mu$.

When working in components you can tell the rank of the tensor that components are associated with by the location of the Greek indices ($v^\mu$ is the $\mu$ component of a vector, $\omega_\mu$ is the $\mu$ component of a covector, etc), however if you want to work with the tensors themselves ($v$, $\omega$, etc) you have no way of knowing its rank from its notation. Abstract index notation solves this by labeling tensors with Latin indices according to their rank, e.g. $v^a$ is a rank $(1,0)$ tensor, $\omega_a$ is a rank $(0,1)$ tensor.

For your example tensor,

- $h_{ab}$ is a rank $(0,2)$ tensor
- $h_{\mu\nu}$ is the $\mu,\nu$ element of a set of rank $(0,0)$ tensors
- $(\mathrm dx^\mu)_a$ is the $\mu$ element of a set of rank $(0,1)$ tensors
- $(\mathrm dx^\nu)_b$ is the $\nu$ element of that same set of rank $(0,1)$ tensors

So to answer your question, for $(\mathrm dx^\mu)_a$, the Latin index $a$ means that this is a rank $(0,1)$ tensor, and the Greek index $\mu$ is the label associated with the ordered basis it belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

$(\mathrm{d}x^1)_a = (\mathrm{d}x)_a$, $(\mathrm{d}x^2)_a = (\mathrm{d}y)_a$, $(\mathrm{d}x^3)_a = (\mathrm{d}z)_a$. In summary, $\mu$ labels which coordinate he is talking about while $a$ is the abstract index.